# At what point does ActiveRecord actually connect to the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, connection

I have a ruby script that is using ActiveRecord (2.3.12) to access a MySQL database.  The flow goes something like, "read database values from a config file", "connect to database", "Create table `A` if it doesn't exist", "download and parse a file", "save parsed records to `A`".

The code looks like the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql',
  :database => database_name,
  :username => username,
  :password => password,
  :host => "localhost",
  :port => 3306
)

  ...

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table a, :force => true do |t|
    t.string :last_name, :limit => 60, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string :first_name, :limit => 30, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string :middle_initial, :limit => 2, :default => ""
    t.string :dob, :limit => 12, :default => "", :null => false
  end
end unless A.table_exists?
```

However, if I put incorrect DB credentials, or a non-existent database name into the `establish_connection` method, the script doesn't seem to give any errors or throw any exceptions until I actually try to perform some operation on the database (i.e., create table `A`).  I tried a `begin-rescue-end` around `establish_connection`, but it never went into the `rescue` block.

Why does `establish_connection` seem to not really...well...establish the connection?  And for the life of me, I can't figure out what it is even supposed to return.  The docs [HERE](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001778) sure don't seem to be any help.

Or am I doing something wrong?  Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use **`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?`** statement to check the whether the ActiveRecord is really connected to database.

```
def establish_database_connection
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection config["database"]
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
    logger.info "Connected to Database"
  rescue Exception => e
    logger.error "Exception db connection :  #{e.message} "
    raise "Database connection failed"
  end
end
```

Without **ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?** statement the above code won't raise any error on invalid credentials.

Answer (score 2):

RSK's solution will leave a connection checked out for the current thread.  If you don't want that, try this (adapted from https://gist.github.com/limhoff-r7/71ee6b1568b604e131a8, which is for Postgres only):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

# Check if the spec passed to `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` can connect to the database.
#
# @return [true] if an active connection can be made to the database using the current config.
# @return [false] if an active connection cannot be made to the database.
def connection_established?
  begin
    # use with_connection so the connection doesn't stay pinned to the thread.
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection {
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
    }
  rescue Exception
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Luke Imhoff: Connections that are manually checked out from ActiveRecord's connection-pool, have to manually be returned to the pool.
As a note, however, I suggest to use the connection that ActiveRecord yields to the block

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { |con| con.active? }
```

Referring to the [documentation of :with_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-with_connection):

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I always assumed that `establish_connection` was more of a connection definition, whereas the actual connection is made when it is used, in this case, when the `table_exists?` runs